# Access inner text using $(this) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have a button and I want to log the inner text using the jQuery when that button is clicked. I know how to use the id to get the text of the buttton (`$("#testID").text()`), but that's not an option for me. I would like to use the `$(this)` keyword instead of the id, but I'm not sure how to do that.

**The html:**

```
<button id="testID" onclick="getButtonText()">Button Text</button>
```

**The javascript:**

```
function getButtonText() {
    console.log("this text = " + $(this).text()); //not working
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass in `this`

**The html:**

```
<button id="testID" onclick="getButtonText(this)">Button Text</button>
```

**The javascript:**

```
function getButtonText(self) {
    console.log("this text = " + $(self).text()); //not working
}
```

Otherwise, `this` will be the `window` object

Comment: So simple, thank you! Can you briefly explain why my solution didn't work?

Comment: @TyRoderick, the last sentence in my answer explains why. When you enter the callback handler and `this` is not bound like in the comment of Jacob Krall, it will default to the `window` object

Comment: @JacobKrall: It would make more sense to do `onclick="getButtonText.call(this);"`. There's no need to create a new function object just to set its `this` value when calling it immediately. If you did use bind, you can drop the extra parens. It's sufficient to do `getButtonText.bind(this)();`

Comment: @squint: yes, you are correct - I've deleted my old comment. @TyRoderick should use an immediate `.call(this)` instead of binding and then invoking the bound expression.

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the caller element to the function...

```js
function getButtonText(element) {
    var $this = $(element);
    console.log("this text = " + $this.text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="testID" onclick="getButtonText(this)">Button Text</button>
```

Though the proper jQuery way of doing it would be like this...

```js
$('#testID').on('click',function() {
  console.log("this text = " + $(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="testID">Button Text</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a class on the button and then whenever a class is click, it will determine the DOM, which is $(this).  Example:

In your html file:
`<button id="testID" class="test-btn">Button Text</button>`

In your script file:

`$(document).ready(function () {

      $(".test-btn").click(function(){
        $("#message").text("The Text is: " + $(this).text() );
      });
    });`

See my example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/e94QraQfCOzGlkirvTJj?p=preview